# How does the weapon cord work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, equipment

When I first came across a weapon cord, I loved the idea of them and their ability to help prevent me from losing a weapon. Ever since then I have been attaching them to any weapon which I solely use.

[Weapon Cord](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-and-armor-accessories#TOC-Weapon-Cord)

> Weapon cords are 2-foot-long leather straps that attach your weapon to your wrist. If you drop your weapon or are disarmed, you can recover it as a move action*, and it never moves any further away from you than an adjacent square. However, you cannot switch to a different weapon without first untying the cord (a full-round action) or cutting it (a move action or an attack, hardness 0, 0 hp). Unlike a locked gauntlet, you can still use a hand with a weapon cord, though a dangling weapon may interfere with finer actions.

What I hate to admit is that I am a bit foggy in how it works in game. I get that the weapon is attached to your wrist by an idiot string.

- But when did you attach it? Do you walk around all day with a strap between your wrist and weapon so its always in the way?
- How long does it take to attach to your wrist? If you haven't done it before combat is it part of drawing the weapon?
- I assume enemies are free to sunder the weapon cord much the same way as any other item you are carrying in battle so that you can fully drop the weapon (and with no hardness or HP this should be an easy task provided they beat your CMD).

Comment: A [*scroll*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls) has 1 hp. ["When an object's hit points reach 0, it's ruined](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects)," too. That's some serious marketing brilliance: charging folks 1 sp for a 2-ft. strip of ruined leather by calling it a weapon cord!

Answer (score 1):

- For walking with it all day attached to your arm, it would be the same for someone walking around with a [Locked Gauntlet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/gauntlet-locked), which seems unpractical and unpolite for some social environments. Imagine a fighter walking around a town with a Greatsword attached to his wrist.

*Example: Imagine a fighter that carries a pair of swords, a greatsword and a falchion, both of them would have a Weapon Cord wrapped around its handle. When the fighter decides to wield one of his swords, he could normally use it, ignoring the Weapon Cord, or he could take a full-round action to wrap the cord around his arm.*

- I would suggest a full-round action to strap it, like it is for unstrapping it.
- I believe they can sunder the weapon cord as well as any item you are carrying. As for strapping the cord

Comment: I would have attaching it as a move action. I expect it to have a small hole in one end which the rest of the cord has been past through so that you put your hand in and then pull it tight.  The full round action to remove is because you have to loosen it rather than untieing it.

Comment: Looks like the end of your answer got cut off.